# Show Information From Database onclick of HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

Hiii Everyone,

In my application,there will be one part which is named as Admin Panel.Where the admin can see the report in highchart based on the student profile completion.
Below is the example page

[image]

My database Example

[image]

Here my chart explains that 2 number of students complete their profile 80-100%.This information is taken from database.similarly i want to get corresponding student information.How can i get details of that student when they onclick of slice in pie chart.Onclick of chart will show the details of students who and all in category of 80-100%.similarly if he click on green it will show the details of students who and all below the category of 40-60% from database.How can i do this if anybody knows the solution please let me know.
Below is my Code

Javascript

```
 <div id="stage" style="padding-bottom:80px;" ></div>

var stage = {
           chart: {
                  renderTo: 'stage',
                  plotBackgroundColor: null,
                  plotBorderWidth: null,
                  plotShadow: false
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'No. of Applicants by Profile Completion'
              },
              tooltip: {
                  formatter: function() {
                      return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y ;
                  }
              },
               credits: {
                    enabled: false
               },
              plotOptions: {
                  pie: {
                      allowPointSelect: true,
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: true,
                          color: '#000000',
                          connectorColor: '#000000',
                          distance: 10,
                          formatter: function() {
                              return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
                          },

                      },

       showInLegend: true
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  type: 'pie',
                  name: '',
                  data: [],
                  dataLabels: {
                  color:'black',
                  distance: -30,   
                  formatter: function () {
                     return '<b style="font-size:16px;">'+ this.y +'</b> ';
                  }
              }
              }]
          }


          $.getJSON("get_stage_chart.php", function(json) {

        stage.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(stage);
          });
```

get_stage_chart.php

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
require "reports.php";
$reports = new reports();
$stages = $reports->stage_report();
$i=0;
foreach ($stages as $stage) {
$name[$i] = $stage['percentage'];
$val[$i] = $stage['users'];
$i++;
}
$jsonData = array();
     $i=0;
  foreach ($stages as $stage) {

           array_push($jsonData,array($name[$i],intval($val[$i])) );
    $i++;
  }
    echo json_encode($jsonData);
    exit;
 ?>
```

reports.php

```
<?php
include ("dbConnection.php");

class reports 
{
     public $link;
    function __construct()
    {
        $dbc = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $dbc->Connect();
        return $this->link;
    }
    public function stage_report()
    {

        $q = $this->link->prepare('SELECT  distinct percentage As percentage,count(percentage) As users from details group by percentage');
        $q->execute();
        $count = $q->fetchall();
        return $count;
    } 
}

?>
```

If anyone give me the solution for my problem it will be very helpful for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can keep that information in custom parameters on each point. I.e {y: 10, customParam: 'your custom text and information'}. Then in [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.point.events) or [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter) extract that from this.point.options.customParam reference.

Comment: i dont understand..can u show me any example code

Comment: Your each point of data should be object. To do that use array() when you create a point in PHP and set parameters like x,y, customParam.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to display after click. But there is an click event in highcharts.

link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.click

On their demo page they provide an example graph: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

The following code is relevant for you. Add it to your plotOptions.pie object

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function (e) {
            // your code for on click
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get corresponding student detail from database and display it in table..this will happen when onclick each slice

Comment: yeah as I already said, just put your logic for retrieving the data in the click function. You can also check the highcharts example for displaying the data